# Hash Match inner join in simple query with in statement

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, tuning

I am running the execution plan for the following query:

```
select m_uid from EmpTaxAudit 
where clientid = 91682 
and  empuid = 42100176452603
and newvalue in('Deleted','DB-Deleted','Added')
```

Here is the execution plan:

[image: Execution Plan]

I have a non clustered index on EmpTaxAudit Table on ClientId and NewValue columns which shows above as 14.9% of the execution:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_EmpTaxAudit_clientid_newvalue] ON [dbo].

[EmpTaxAudit]
(
    [ClientID] ASC,
    [NewValue] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

I also have a non clustered unique index PK as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmpTaxAudit] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_EmpTaxAudit] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientID] ASC,
    [EmpUID] ASC,
    [m_uid] ASC,
    [m_eff_start_date] ASC,
    [ReplacedOn] ASC,
    [ColumnName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

Trigger code in source table EmpTax:

```
CREATE                trigger [dbo].[trins_EmpTax]
on [dbo].[emptax]
for insert
as
begin
  declare 
    @intRowCount  int,
      @user          varchar(30)

  select @intRowCount = @@RowCount
  IF @intRowCount > 0 
  begin
     select @user = suser_sname()

     insert EmpTaxAudit (Clientid, empuid,m_uid,m_eff_start_date, ColumnName, ReplacedOn, ReplacedBy, OldValue,dblogin,newvalue)
     select Clientid, empuid,m_uid,m_eff_start_date,'taxcode', getdate(),IsNull(userid,@user), '', Left(@user,15),'Added'
        from inserted i
         where m_uid not in (select m_uid from EmpTaxAudit 
                    where clientid = i.clientid  and (newvalue = 'Deleted'
            or newvalue = 'DB-Deleted'
                        or newvalue = 'Added') and  empuid = i.empuid)
       and i.m_eff_end_date is null 

     insert EmpTaxAudit (Clientid, empuid,m_uid,m_eff_start_date, ColumnName, ReplacedOn, ReplacedBy, OldValue,dblogin,newvalue)
     select Clientid, empuid,m_uid,m_eff_start_date,'taxcode', getdate(),IsNull(userid,@user), '', Left(@user,15),'Deleted'
        from inserted i
         where m_uid not in (select m_uid from EmpTaxAudit 
                    where clientid = i.clientid  and (newvalue = 'Deleted'
            or newvalue = 'DB-Deleted'
                        or newvalue = 'Added') and  empuid = i.empuid)
       and i.m_eff_end_date is not null 


  end
end
```

What can I do to avoid the high cost of Hash Match (Inner Join)?

Thanks!

Comment: But is the query really slow? These numbers (74%, 11%, 14.9%) are not very useful.

Comment: It is not slow for a single record but this is called from a multi-row insert trigger which is very slow

Comment: Just added the trigger. Do you need the create table for EmpTaxAudit?

Comment: Is there some particular reason you don't have a clustering index defined (or perhaps you didn't include it in your example)?  No clustering index creates a heap and they can frequently perform sub-optimally.  You could 'try' clustering' your primary key to see if that makes any difference.  Posting the xml for the execution plan might give us more to go on.

Answer (score 3):

For the 1st query, an index that uses all three columns from the `WHERE` clause and includes the column from the `SELECT` list would be much more useful:

```
-- index suggestion A
(clientid, empuid, newvalue) INCLUDE (m_uid)
```

or an index targeted specifically for this query:

```
-- index suggestion B
(clientid, empuid, m_uid)
WHERE newvalue in ('Deleted', 'DB-Deleted', 'Added')
```

---

Regarding the trigger, some comments:

- The first query you show does not appear in the trigger. What appears is a join from that table to the `inserted` rows to another table (which has the trigger).
- My suggestion B above seems better suited to be used by the trigger.
- The trigger has 2 almost identical `insert` statements. Why? I think they could be combined in one - and simpler - insert and using `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`:

  ```
  insert EmpTaxAudit 
    ( Clientid, empuid, m_uid, m_eff_start_date, ColumnName, 
      ReplacedOn, ReplacedBy, OldValue, dblogin, 
      newvalue
    )
  select 
      Clientid, empuid, m_uid, m_eff_start_date, 'taxcode',
      getdate(), IsNull(userid,@user), '', Left(@user,15),
      case when m_eff_end_date is null 
          then 'Added' else 'Deleted'
      end
  from inserted i
  where not exists 
        ( select 1 
          from EmpTaxAudit 
          where m_uid = i.m_uid 
            and clientid = i.clientid  
            and empuid = i.empuid
            and newvalue in ('Deleted', 'DB-Deleted', 'Added')
        ) ;
  ```

Comment: Nice explanation with suggestion A & B. For +1

Answer (score 1):

**Reason for Hash Match (inner join) :**

> "a Hash Match  join occurs when SQL Server joins two tables by hashing
>   the rows from the smaller of the two tables to be joined, and then
>   inserting them into a hash table, then processing the larger table one
>   row at a time against the smaller hashed table, looking for  matches
>   where rows need to be joined. Because the smaller of the tables
>   provides the values in the hash table, the table size is kept at a
>   minimum, and because hashed values instead of real values are used,
>   comparisons can be made very quickly. As long as the table that is
>   hashed is relatively small, this can be a quick process. On the other
>   hand, if both tables are very large, a Hash Match join can be very
>   inefficient as compared to other types of joins."

So clearly your smaller table return 16 rows and larger one return 1,41,000 rows.Here smaller table is hash which is quite good, now it will join to 1,41,000 rows so cost has to be more and execution time has to be slow.

you have to minimize number of rows return in large table.you are getting index seek in both case so index is being utilize.

I think you only need to rewrite trigger query.

```
CREATE  trigger [dbo].[trins_EmpTax]
on [dbo].[emptax]
for insert
as
begin

if @@rowcount = 0 
        return
    set nocount on

  declare 
    @intRowCount  int,
      @user          varchar(30)

  --select @intRowCount = @@RowCount
  if exists(select * from inserted)
  begin
     select @user = suser_sname()

     insert EmpTaxAudit (Clientid, empuid,m_uid,m_eff_start_date, ColumnName, ReplacedOn, ReplacedBy, OldValue,dblogin,newvalue)
     select Clientid, empuid,m_uid,m_eff_start_date,'taxcode', getdate(),IsNull(userid,@user), '', Left(@user,15)
     ,case when i.m_eff_end_date is null then 'Added' else 'Deleted' END
        from inserted i
         where not exists (select m_uid from EmpTaxAudit ETA
                    where i.m_uid=ETA.m_uid and  empuid = i.empuid and clientid = i.clientid  
                    and newvalue in('Deleted','DB-Deleted' , 'Added') 
                    )


     --insert EmpTaxAudit (Clientid, empuid,m_uid,m_eff_start_date, ColumnName, ReplacedOn, ReplacedBy, OldValue,dblogin,newvalue)
     --select Clientid, empuid,m_uid,m_eff_start_date,'taxcode', getdate(),IsNull(userid,@user), '', Left(@user,15),'Deleted'
     --   from inserted i
     --    where m_uid not in (select m_uid from EmpTaxAudit 
     --               where clientid = i.clientid  and (newvalue = 'Deleted'
     --       or newvalue = 'DB-Deleted'
     --                   or newvalue = 'Added') and  empuid = i.empuid)
     --  and i.m_eff_end_date is not null 


  end
end
```

Notice that you can correct condition inside `NOT EXISTS` clause which is minor,rest it will work perfect and perform better.

Also care to explain that what is clustered index on this table and why so many composite primary key.?

Answer (score -1):

First critique: I don't think a `PRIMARY KEY` should consist of so many fields.  A primary key is just meant to be a simple identifier of uniqueness.  Arguably you could have two fields in your PK for many-to-many intersection tables, though I personally always have a single-field primary key, even for these.  So I'd say your PK `PK_EmpTaxAudit` really should be redefined as a unique index.

Then I would suggest adding `newvalue` to the `INCLUDE` fields of that index:

```
create unique index IX_EmpTaxAudit(
  [ClientID] ASC,
  [EmpUID] ASC,
  [m_uid] ASC,
  [m_eff_start_date] ASC,
  [ReplacedOn] ASC,
  [ColumnName] ASC
)
include (newvalue)
```

I suspect that will give you a neater execution plan.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should have a clustered index (with FILLFACTOR<=95) on the tables to avoid high IO. Because HEAP cause to more fragmentation. So, you can replace PK Non Clustered Index with Clustered.

Apart from that to avoid HASH_MATCH you should have all the columns being used in SELECT statement and WHERE clause should be within a index. So either you replace the non clustered index **idx_EmpTaxAudit_clientid_newvalue** with bellow one ore create new non clustered index.

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_EmpTaxAudit_clientid_newvalue] ON [dbo].

    [EmpTaxAudit]
    (
        [ClientID] ASC,
        [NewValue] ASC,
        [newvalue]
    )
    INCLUDE (m_uid)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

**Reason of HASH_MATCH**

SQL Server Optimizer prefer to use index instead of HEAP. So, in your case requested data and columns in where condition lies on two different index. That's why SQL Server Optimizer used both indexes and performed HASH_MATCH.

Thanks